# How/To Link Bootstrap Resume to a button

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap resume that I would like to have linked to a button on my portfolio webpage. I'm still learning and new to this, so forgive me if this appears to be a weird question.

When I attempt to do it through an  href tag, once the button is clicked, it won't load it, but the browser seems to understand where I wanted it to go, because it has the name of the link on a bare webpage.

I also linked the bootstrap stylesheet below the beginning  tag in HTML.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A href attribute on a button won't work only on links `<a>`. You could use javascript for this.

```html
<button onclick="location.href='https://google.com';">resume</button>
```

replace https://google.com with your own link.